# How to validate textbox on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Javascript

```
 <script>
    function isNumberKey(evt) {

        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode 
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            alert("Please Enter Only Numeric Value:");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#TextBox2').keydown(isNumberKey);         

        $('#TextBox3').keydown(isNumberKey);
    });

</script>
```

Here is a code to enter only numeric value in textbox.
When I select value from dropdownlist . This validation doesn't work

```
Select Category:

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Catname" DataValueField="catId" AutoPostBack="True">                      
    </asp:DropDownList>       
  Name:

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Enter Name" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    Price :<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Enter Price" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   

    Quantity
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Enter Quantity" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

How to validate all time when I select from dropdownlist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the change event

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function () {
    var val = this.value;
    // Validation
});
```

Comment: @Ghost ok, your has `AutoPostBack="True"`. When the DropDown change fired the event to the server side.

Comment: @Ghost sets `AutoPostBack="False"` to capture the event with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to have a Event for Select change for your dropdown. You should write your code inside a JQuery change Event. Or you could use

```
$("#DropDownList1").change(function(){
 //your validation code
})
```

Or you could use OnSelectedIndexChanged() and write c# code for your validation

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Your c# code
 string message = "Your Message";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + 
"');", true);
}
```

Comment: you could get the selected item by the following code inside OnSelectedIndexChanged()  string text=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;            string value=DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;

Comment: @Ghost then you can use JQuery change() function